# why it is unable to sort by patient id?

Tags: jquery, datatable

am using datatables to list out patient details. here am unable to sort this by patientid. these values are getting from db. patientid is a varchar type on database.

am using "aaSorting": [[ 1,'desc']], to sort patientid as default. but these are not in sorted order.
how to solve this ?

image was attached. please find.

[image]

Comment: hi, you can parse string to int before showing it. then it will work proper.

Comment: Can we see a live example? At the moment, there is not nearly enough information to help.

Answer (score 0):

It is sorting correctly, but as text.
You need to tell datatables to consider that column as numeric.

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "aoColumnDefs": [
        { "sType": "numeric" }
    ]
} );
```

You can get more information from the docs.  http://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting

Comment: thanks for your reply, but it is not working. even properties of datatable also loosing

Answer (score 0):

it was corrected. have used  $pid  . replaced with $pid. Now it was working fine. Thanks for all.

Comment: OK, thanks. Please don't abandon questions, since someone may help you when you no longer need it. Always add the solution, as you have done, and then tick it to remove the question from 'unanswered' lists.